# ¿Cómo solucionar el problema System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.' en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de crear un código que cree las tablas de multiplicar y me tira ese error cuando en: `numero=Conver.ToInt32(generar.Text);`

```
namespace Daniel_Zet_Pág_85_Tablas_de_Multiplicar
{
    public partial class tablas : Form
    {
        public tablas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Programa que genera tablas de multiplicar
            //Se declaran las variables
            int cuenta, numero, v;

            //Se lee y asigna el dato
            numero= Convert.ToInt32(generar.Text);

            //Se inicia el ciclo for
            for (cuenta=1; cuenta <=12; cuenta++)//se inicia en 1 hasta 12
            {
                v = numero * cuenta;
                listBox1.Items.Add(numero + "*" + cuenta + "=" + v);
            }
        }

        private void limpia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y... ya pusiste un punto de interrupción antes del `Convert.ToInt32` para saber qué es lo que `generar.Text` devuelve?

Comment: Contiene generar.Text comma (,), punto (.) o está vacio?

Answer (score 0):

También deberías intentar con int.TryParse() .
La sintaxis es la siguiente:

int.TryParse(generar.Text, out numero);